# header and footer change apply to all sub pages

Tags: html, css, html4

My website was done in html page
www.synclairepower.com
it contain one home page and 25 sub category pages
i want change the address in header so iam editing in all 25 sub pages is there any way if i change the header at one time apply to all sub category pages at a time because header and footer will be the same matter 
is there any way by giving div tag

but div tags id are only for css

i will make the all changes if it is possible because every time i want to change many-thing in header and footer

so please tell me what should to do

if you know the answer or same question please give me the link because ididnt find it

Answer (score 0):

pageA.php :

```
include('header.php') ;

// Your stuff for page A here

include('footer.php') ;
```

header.php :

```
<div id="head">Your head...</div>
```

footer.php :

```
<div id="footer">Tour footer...</div>
```

This is a bit basical PHP, you really need to look at some starting php tutorials